# How to simulate a signal of a particular frequency according to the number of points in a period of the signal?

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis, filter-design, lowpass-filter

I have one period data ($n$ points in total) of a signal. I want to generate a periodic signal with a total of $m$ points and corresponding signal frequency of $F$ according to this data. How do I do that? Besides, I want to design a low-pass filter according to the simulated periodic signal, $F_s$ and $F_{stop}$ need to be set in `fdatool`. How to calculate $F_s$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the $n$ points (hereafter, the *chunk*) precisely divide the base period (which you don't know yet)  evenly. You are lucky. You can verify that by concatenating  the $n$  discrete samples  (or possibly $n-1$ consecutive ones)
by an integer number $K$ of (periodic) repetitions (copy-paste, several times, hereafter the *chain*), with $Kn\ge m$ (or $K(n-1)\ge m$. It should be smooth  visually. The FFT of the chunk and the chain should be superposable (with appropriate scaling in time and amplitude).
Then, crop the chain of $Kn$ samples to $m$.

Then, using a non-parametric (discrete Fourier transform, FFT), you can estimate the spectrum of the (underlying) continuous data, and find the minimum Nyquist sampling frequency, which may differ from the original one (the initial sampling).